# How to create a 3D irregular lattice using shapefile centroids and attribute values

Tags: r, 3d, spatial

I would like to be able to create a 3D surface using centroids extracted from shapefiles for the {x,y} coordinates and attribute values merged to the shapefile for the {z} coordinates.

For example, say the shapefile contains three polygons with IDs A B and C, and we have a separate attribute table:

```
attribute_df <- as.data.frame(ID=c("A", "B", "C"), value = c(1.3, 0.8, 0.4))
```

The aim would be to :

1. Merge attribute_df to the shapefile by `ID`.
2. Extract the centroids of each shapefile, providing the {x, y} coordinates
3. Use the corresponding attribute values to provide the {z} coordinates.

The output would therefore be something like:

```
output <- data.frame(
ID=c("A", "B", "C"), 
x_pos=c(0.4, 0.8, 1.4), 
y_pos=c(0.9, 0.3, 1.6),
z_pos=c(1.3, 0.8, 0.4)
)
```

Which could be then used to render a 3D surface using `rgl` or similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the attribute table always has the same IDs, in the same order, as the shapefile, this is trivial.  Are you looking for a general pattern-matching method?

Comment: It wouldn't always be the same so a general method would be good.